# App reporting privacy - is there any?

Tags: google-play-store, privacy

When you report an app (for violation) through Google Play, does the developer have access to (any parts of) your Google identity? Does the fact that you've reported this app show up in any of your public (or private) Google records? Does Google have an official policy on that?

Comment: When you say "report", do you mean reporting a bug (e.g. from the force-close dialog), or reporting a violation of the content policy from the Play Store app or website?

Comment: Reporting a violation. let me edit that post. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a pop up every time you submit a report for the privacy policy.

But regardless, pretty much every Google system and API is covered by the same privacy policy:  http://www.google.com/policies/privacy/